# Android React Native App Builds In Android Studio But Not Using The React Native CLI

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I am able to build my app Using `Run` in Android Studio, but using the React Native CLI which I prefer, the app will not build using the `react-native run-android` command.

Using the React Native CLI, I get the error message:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> react_9eow0duexig9bim4oxa9fkqs2$_run_closure4$_closure6$_closure10$_closure18
```

There are plenty of online posts about referencing the first line of the error of which none of the solutions fix the build, but there are literally no google results when searching for the second line.

Why would Android Studio be able to build the app when the React Native CLI can't?

I'm using RN v 0.61.4

Any help much appreciated.